# How can I avoid autocomplete dropdown appearing when text is programmatically set?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in my layout.  I also have an alternative way to select the same items which are present in the AutoCompleteTextView.  When the alternative way is selected, I populate the value in the AutoCompleteTextView via:

```
autoCompleteTextView.setText(valueFromAlternativeSource);
```

where `valueFromAlternativeSource` is one of the valid auto complete options.  The trouble with this is that the autocomplete dropdown appears when setText is called. Putting the following line after the above doesn't work:

```
autoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();  //Doesn't work.  Why?
```

Any ideas on why dismiss dropdown isn't working or other ways I could dismiss the dropdown?

Comment: Your solution does not work because setText(CharSequence) method starts asynchronous work. Whenever the text changes, the filter of the Adapter is used to filter for possible proposals to show. Since the filter can take a long time, it is called asynchronously. Some time later the filter returns and its results get displayed when the UI thread gets processing time again. At this point in time the dismissDropDown() method has long been completed – which is why this method has no effect whatsoever."
Source: http://www.grokkingandroid.com/how-androids-autocompletetextview-nearly-drove-me-nuts/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to support API<17, Subclass AutoCompleteTextview and override `setText(text, filter)` method

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, boolean filter) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=17) {
        super.setText(text, filter);
    }else{
        if(filter){
            setText(text);
        }else{
            ListAdapter adapter = getAdapter();
            setAdapter(null);
            setText(text);
            if(adapter instanceof ArrayAdapter)
                setAdapter((ArrayAdapter) adapter);
            else
                setAdapter((CursorAdapter) adapter);
            //if you use more types of Adapter you can list them here
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever you want to set the text manually call `setText(text, false)`

Comment: Best answer here just for the API<17 support!

Answer (score 16):

This works fine for me and is less complex:

```
ListAdapter adapter = autoCompleteTextView.getAdapter();
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(null);
autoCompleteTextView.setText("whatever");
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: great,  but I have to assign the adapter again before set adapter, and works fine for show hide

Answer (score 7):

Looks like its a problem of the order how messages are processed.
My work around looks like this:

```
//autoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        autoCompleteTextView.dismissDropDown();
}});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
autoCompleteTextView.setText(valueFromOtherMeans, filter);

     * @param filter If <code>false</code>, no filtering will be performed
     *        as a result of this call.
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add some prosa to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

My solution (but I don't like it, there must be something better):

```
autoCompleteTextView.setText(valueFromAlternativeSource);
autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(0);

autoCompleteTextView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   }
}
```